# View Decision Tree in Spark (Scala) as if -then-else string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have built a decision tree in pyspark (dtModel) using library DecisionTreeRegressor and it can be viewed in the if-then-else format using the code

```
print dtModel.stages[-1]._java_obj.toDebugString()
```

How can I view the same using scala if I am using the same library (DecisionTreeRegressor).

Using the code

```
println(dtModel.stages(-1).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeRegressor].toDebugString())
```

Gives an error

```
<console>:62: error: value stages is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.Model[_$4]
              println(dtModel.stages(-1).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeRegressor].toDebugString())
                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following command:

```
dtModel.stages(2).asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel].toDebugString
```